# Modular Arithmetic and Residue Classes

Tags: number-theory

Trying to solve the following:

$(2*{4^n})\equiv4\pmod7$

for $n \in \Bbb N$ .
Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Also is it appropriate to divide by 4 in modular equations?

Comment: Experiment! See what happens if $n=1,2,3,\dots$.

Comment: I realize that when n=2,5,8 etc. but how do i show that it's true.

Comment: Since $2\equiv 4^{-1}\mod 7$, we have that $2*4^n\equiv 4^{n-1}\mod 7$, thus the congruence equation is equivalent to $4^{n-1}\equiv4\mod 7$, which is also equivalent to $4^{n-2}\equiv1\mod 7$. Since $3$ is the minimal positive integer such that $4^3\equiv1\mod 7$, we must have that $3$ divide $n-2$. Hence the congruence equation holds if and only if $n\equiv2\mod 3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Note that $4^3\equiv 1\pmod{7}$. So if $n$ is a solution, so is $n+3$. Conversely, if $n\gt 3$ is a solution, so is $n-3$.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo $7$, as $2$ is a unit, the equation is equivalent to $4^n=2^{2n}\equiv 2\iff 2^{2n-1}\equiv 1\mod 7$.

Now $2$ has order $3$ modulo $7$. So he solutions are
$$2n\equiv 1\mod 3\iff n\equiv 2\mod 3 $$
since $2$ is its own inverse modulo $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. For any integer $k,$ if $k$ is not divisible by $7$ then $[\;x\equiv y \pmod 7 \iff k x\equiv k y \pmod 7\;].$ So with $k=2$ we have $2.4^2\equiv 4 \pmod 7 \iff 2.2.4^n\equiv 2.4\pmod 7 \iff 4^{n+1}\equiv 8 \pmod 7\iff 4^{n+1}\equiv 1 \pmod 7.$